# Can't get link locator of element

Tags: robotframework

Absolute beginner here.

I want my script to click on the **Team** tab of this website http://www.robotframeworktutorial.com/front-office/

My code is the following:

```
Load TeamPage
     Click Link    css=#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1 > ul > li:nth-child(5) >a
```

I get the following error:

```
Link with locator 'css=#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1 > ul > li:nth-child(5) > a' not found.
```

I have tried to use xpath and just the element's text with no success.
Any help is deeply appreciated.

Comment: Share the DOM please.

Answer (score 1):

May be problem with the long CSS locator. You can use the simple xpath for navigating to the **TEAMS** tab.
the xpath for the Teams tab is   - `//a[@href="#team"]`

This worked for me -

```
open browser     ${URL}    Chrome       executable_path=${path}
click element       //a[@href="#team"]
```

**output-**

[image]